# Variavel retornando Undefined

Tags: php

Tenho esse trecho de código e os inputs, quando clico para editar a cidade e clico para salvar funciona normal, agora se eu não altero a cidade, ela passa
como undefined e não consigo salvar. Como posso fazer para que quando eu não
altere a cidade armazene do mesmo jeito?

```
if ($street === $streetOriginal && $town === $townOriginal){

    $stmtSaveAddress = $conn->prepare("UPDATE address SET street = :street, number = :number, town = :town, complement = 
                                      :complement, city_id = (select city.city_id from city where city.link = :cityLink)
                                      WHERE address_id = :address");

    $stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':street', $street);
    $stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':number', ($number <= 0 ? NULL : $number));
    $stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':town', $town);
    $stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':cityLink', $city);
    $stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':complement', $complement);
    $stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':address', $addressId);


    echo 'city: '.$city;



    if ($stmtSaveAddress->execute()) {
        echo 'trueaddress';
    }else{
        echo 'falseaddress';

   }
```

Form:

```
<div class="inputs-without-icon" id="box-city">
   <input id="city" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="*Cidade" list="cities-list" value="<?php echo "{$Menu->getAddressCityName()} - {$Menu->getAddressState()}"; ?>" onkeyup="charByCharCity(this.value);">
   <input id="street" type="text" placeholder="*Rua" maxlength="70" value="<?php echo $Menu->getAddressStreet(); ?>">   
</div>
<datalist id="cities-list"><option data-number='0' value='Nome - Estado'>Cardápios</datalist>
```

Esse é meu form.

Comment: O que é undefined e onde?

Comment: o `$city` está vindo como undefined quando não clico no input e altero a cidade, mas quando eu não altero deve salvar do mesmo jeito, ou seja permanecer a que já está lá.

Comment: É um checkbox? poderia colocar o form tbm.

Comment: @rray é um input, na verdade quando clico sobre o input e digito por exemplo a letra C, ele me lista todas as cidades com C, aí seleciono alguma e clico em salvar ele salva normal. Agora se eu por exemplo alterar a rua e não alterar a cidade ele não deixa inserir. Quando dou um alert em city ele me passa undefined quando eu nao altero.

Comment: Parece ser um problema de javascript, já os inputs não tem name, então o js deve fazer um algum processo antes de enviar as informações para o php.

Comment: No js eu pego os valores que estão no input e então vio ajax envio para meu arquivo php aonde dou o update. @rray

Answer (score 0):

```
//Se quando vir undefined não é pra alterar o dado você faz assim:
if(isset($city)&&$city!=null){
   if ($stmtSaveAddress->execute()) {
       echo 'trueaddress';
   }else{
       echo 'falseaddress';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você quer fazer o update independente se houve alteração nos dados ou não, correto?

Nesse caso basta você fazer o update sem passar por qualquer teste lógico.

```
    $stmtSaveAddress = $conn->prepare("UPDATE address SET street = :street, number = :number, town = :town, complement = 
                                  :complement, city_id = (select city.city_id from city where city.link = :cityLink)
                                  WHERE address_id = :address");

$stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':street', $street);
$stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':number', ($number <= 0 ? NULL : $number));
$stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':town', $town);
$stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':cityLink', $city);
$stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':complement', $complement);
$stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':address', $addressId);


echo 'city: '.$city;



if ($stmtSaveAddress->execute()) {
    echo 'trueaddress';
}else{
    echo 'falseaddress';
}
```